# ¿Cómo puedo crear una clase en Android Java para crear y leer archivos de texto?

Tags: java, android

He intentado hacer una clase para poder crear y leer archivos de texto en Android Studio, sin embargo, los tutoriales que he seguido se enfocan en el uso de las activity, he hecho los cambios correspondientes pero no he podido crear una clase APARTE, que NO sea un activity que realice estas funciones.

```
package com.example.apk;

import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.File; import java.io.FileReader; import java.io.FileWriter; import java.io.IOException; import java.io.InputStreamReader; import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Datos extends AppCompatActivity {

public String porcentaje = "a";

public Datos(){

}

public void Dt(String ruta) {
    if (!ruta.isEmpty()) {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "datos");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        try {
            File gpxfile = new File(file, "porcentaje");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append("Hola");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            porcentaje = readFile();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved your text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}

private String readFile() {
    File fileEvents = new File(this.getFilesDir()+"/datos/porcentaje");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileEvents));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    this.porcentaje = text.toString();
    return this.porcentaje;
}
}
```

Comment: Porque estarás siguiendo tutoriales de Android y no de Java. El problema que planteas es de java. Y como programas en java, puedes definir clases java y usarlas como en cualquier programa java que no tenga nada que ver con Android., definiendo objetos de esas clases. Obviamente para hacer aplicaciones para Android, usando java, tienes que usar el SDK de Android, en el que hay clases Activity y todo lo que hace que tu aplicación funcione en Android.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es una clase de Java que no extienda a `Activity` puedes crear dicha clase con los métodos de lectura y escritura:

```
public class FileController {
    private File mFile;

    public FileController(@NonNull File file) {
        mFile = file;
    }

    public boolean addContentToFile(String content) {
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(mFile);
            fileWriter.append(content);
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String readFile() {
        String content = "";
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(mFile));
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                content += scanner.nextLine();
            }
            return content;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Luego desde tu actividad puedes instanciar un objeto `FileController` y hacer las operaciones que desees

```
File dir = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "datos");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdir();
}

FileController controller = new FileController(new File(dir, "porcentaje.txt"));
controller.addContentToFile("10%\n15%");
String content = controller.readFile();
if (content != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```